# NullPointerException at KotlinxSerializer when GET returns null instead of a List

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, kotlinx.serialization

Using Ktor I'm fetching a List like this, which in some cases returns null.

```
override suspend fun getDevices(accessToken: String): List<Device>? {
    return client.get {
        url(path = "/devices")
        header("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")
    }
}
```

However, when the backend returns null I get an Exception:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err:     at io.ktor.client.features.json.serializer.KotlinxSerializer.read(KotlinxSerializer.kt:37)
```

What is the best approach here? I think the easiest would be to adjust the backend to return [] instead of null, but can it be solved on the client side? Or is there a general agreement that the backend should return [] instead of null?

Comment: `when the backend returns null I get an Exception:` Well you only will get a NullPointerException if you use that returned null. So check for null before use i would say. Please post the code that tries to use that null.

Comment: `when the backend returns null` ? What kind of backend is that? A https server? I wonder what you have in mind if you say that a server returns [] or null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that any `JsonSerializer` in Ktor can deserialize JSON text only to a non-nullable object because of the `read` method signature:

```
fun read(type: TypeInfo, body: Input): Any
```

The `NullPointerException` is thrown because at the end of that method the [!!](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator) operator is used for converting a value to a non-null type.

As a workaround, you can catch the `NullPointerException` and return `null` value. This behavior will be fixed in Ktor 2.0.0.

Comment: Was using this workaround, but wondering may be there's another way. Anyway your answer cleared my doubts, thanks!